# How to use parent category with groups when using selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

Given the app shown below, how can I allow the user to select `boring` or `basic`, i.e. categories with no subgroups, and have that selection stored in the input object and thus reflected in the `renderText` statement? Also, for some reason, only `boring` is showing up in the choice list, not `basic`.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("selection", 
                "Select Something:",
                list("Boring" = " ",
                     "Positive" = c("Cool", "Groovy", "Rad"),
                     "Basic" = " ",
                     "Taco" = c("Bell", "Hell")),
                selected = "Groovy"
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$selection)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: You could remove = " "

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for clarifying. Only issue is that is messing up the order. Do you know if any way to retain original order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retain the order as you stated.

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "selection",
      "Select Something:",
choices = list("Boring" = list("Boring"),
        "Positive" = c("Cool", "Groovy", "Rad"),
        "Basic" = list("Basic"),
        "Taco" = c("Bell", "Hell")),
      selected = "Groovy"
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$selection)
    })
  }
)
```

Without repetition of names:

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "selection",
      "Select Something:",
      choices = list(
        "Boring",
        "Positive" = c("Cool", "Groovy", "Rad"),
        "Basic",
        "Taco" = c("Bell", "Hell")
      ),
      selected = "Groovy",
      selectize = FALSE
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$selection)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: This gets at it, but I don't want the option repeated (i.e. once in group name then a second time in the options for that group)

Comment: selectize = FALSE might be used. Then recommend to use it across all selectInputs.